# Validate multiple fields to be unique in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My table is named `Cars` with 2 fields `(id, matriculation)`, how to adapt my syntax below?

```
'input_field' => 'unique:<table name>,<column name for this input field>, <unique id>, <unique id column in table>';
```

I have tried this: ???

```
 'matriculation' => 'required|unique:cars,matriculation, uniqueID ???? , unique id colum in table ????
```

Do know you what is  the `unique id` and `unique id column` ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you doing update or create?

Comment: @Caddy DZ: the update in fact..

Comment: Do you want to update the `marticulation` only? or both `marticulation` and `ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate the `matriculation` upon update to be unique but keep the `id` intact, force ignoring it with a custom Validator rule

```php
$car = Get_The_Car_Here; // Here assign the car to a variable
Validator::make($data, [
    'marticulation' => [
        'required',
        \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('cars')->ignore($car->id),
    ],
]);
```

Hope this helps